# Is there a shortcut to converting an XML file to an XLS file in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

For a project at work, my program should open a newly added excel file every day and export data to database. I have code written that should theoretically do that, but turns out the guy who wrote the program for those excel files to go onto the sharepoint site has them named as XLS but has them formatted as XML type. Without having to go into his program to fix that (even if that is easier), what is a quick way to convert types? Or would using an XML reader just be faster?

Comment: I would suggest that the best way to pump data from a file to DB is connect to XLS file using Microsoft.ACE.OleDb provider and work with the Excel file like if it was DB. So, you read one DataReader and apply your SQL using data reader values to RDMS. If you have already some files in XML format, you can probably use Excel to open these file and then SaveAs XLS

Answer (score 0):

XML is OK, and easier to work with than xls. You can use xslt, linq to xml.. If your program is using Office Interop, just specify the file is in Office 2003 XML format.

Comment: In case of import/export data from/to XLS files, you can do it easily, as if it was DB, if you use ACE.OleDb provider. No need for interop. Interop is ok on desktop but on server it is bad thing